# Which method does Spring Data Rest use to extract entity from query parameter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

For example, we have a request like this:

```
GET /orders/search
{
    "user": "http://example.org/users/1",
    ...
}
```

In what way does Spring Data Rest retrieve the User Entity from an URL? Does it use Regex to retrieve the id 1 then query it or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If yo are wondering about spring data repository, you need to use this method.

User user = userRepository.findById(Integer id);

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what i'm wondering. From the request above Spring Data Rest magically turn `"user": "http://example.org/users/1"` to an User Entity. your code is that last part of it, i think. But which method does Spring Data Rest use to convert the `"http://example.org/users/1"` url to `Integer id` so that it can use the `findById` method?

Comment: I think you are looking for controller correct? If yes, this will be your controller mapping.        

@GetMapping(“/users/{id})
public User getUserById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
// Return Service call to get users from repository.  
}

Comment: I don't think you read my question through. The endpoint here is `/orders/search`, the request body is `{
    "user": "http://example.org/users/1"
}`
the method handler will have something like this `findOrderByUser(User user);`
the thing is, how can Spring Data Rest get the User entity from an Url?

Comment: Making another Get request will be unlikely because it's inefficient and the thing that `@GetMapping(“/users/{id})` returns is often not the User entity anymore but a modified one.